# creating an additional data access layer on top of mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For my `node.js` app, I am using `mongodb` as the database. Also i prefer to use `mongoose.js` on top of it. My question is,

> is it justifiable to build an additional layer on top of `mongoose.js`
>   so as to access the data?. Like for `CRUD operations`?

like a generic function set which does exactly what `mongoose` does and limiting coders from writing directly `mongoose` queries and may be helping at a later stage when we change the db or `mongoose`. I am asking this because i cant see how much effective this will be at a later stage but seems annoying now. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to answer definitively, but I tend to have this 'extra' layer for easier testability.  E.g. easier to test classes/files in isolation.  Also useful if you'd like to be able to refactor another data storage at some point.